# How to set custom xhr header with PJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

I'm trying to set a custom header with pJax so I can render things on the server side. Per the [pjax docs](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax), I can use `pjax:beforeSend` to set xhr headers.

Getting the following error:

```
typeerror xhr.setrequestheader is not a function
```

The code i've tried:

```
$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function(xhr) { 
    if ($(event.target).data('rendertimeline') !== undefined) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-RENDERTIMELINE', 'true');
    }
});
```

basically, i'm adding a data attribute to certain links and would link to check for that attribute. if its there, send a custom HTTP header along side the standard HTTP_X_PJAX header. Seemed fairly simple but i'm coming up short somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried logging `xhr` to ensure it's actually the request? I'm not familiar with jQuery's handling of XmlHttpRequests, but perhaps you're not getting what you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have started using PJAX recently first argument is not xhr but event object add that and it should work.Don't know why they skipped it in docs but most events like start,end etc will have *event* as their first argument .

```
$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function(event,xhr, options)
```

Comment: I think you're on the right track. Now that I look at my code, I do see that i'm using `event` without an event argument however the header is still not setting even after adding event to the arguments list. If I add  if I add the setRequestHeader code to pJax's options.beforeSend function (line 206 in jquery.pjax.js) -- it works just fine.. Any reason it may not be calling from my own script but works from within the library?